# How to change the default link color in Google Slides?

Tags: links, google-slides, text-formatting

I have a presentation in Google Slides. Every new link is colored cyan by default and all existing links have this default color as well. How could I change this default color that determines the color of new links and of existing links that have not been manually reformatted?

- I don't want to fix each link individually.
- I know I can edit the master slides but that  seems to only allow changing the layout of the slides and the formatting of lists, not the links.
- If I pick a new theme for the presentation that changes the link color but it also changes everything else, which I don't want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a somewhat similar problem and found the following solution:

1) Open the Master Slide;

2) Select "Colors..." at the top of the Master Slide;
[image]

3) At the "Theme colors" dialog (right-hand side of the screen), select "Link";

4) Pick the desired link color and it is finished...

Comment: I can't seem to find any "Colors..." button/link/label at the top of the master slide. Could you post a screenshot highlighting the "Colors..." part? Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot included...

Comment: Interesting! I don't have any more buttons after "Background..."! But thanks for the screenshot anyway, maybe it will help others.

Comment: Update: I tried it with my private account as well. I created a brand new presentation in both cases, using the same browser. With my private account I have a "Colors..." button there indeed. Using my work account though, there is no such button. Strange!

Comment: Thanks for this! I got to the the *Theme colors* dialog by selecting *Edit theme* from the *Slide* menu.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "slide" and then "edit theme".  Here, you can choose the master slide at the top.  On the right hand side is a theme menu.  Select "link" and change the color there.  It works in a work account - you don't have to be in your personal account.

Answer (score -2):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select all of your hyperlinks. After that go to your tool bar and change the colour to whatever you choose.

Comment: Does not change the _default_ color.