# How to make hyperlinked buttons change color once clicked in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I am creating a game in Google Slides kind of 'Are you smarter than a 5th grader?' but without the money part, just questions.

On the first slide are buttons with categories hyperlinked to questions in the succeeding slides.

How can I loop back to the first slide and find that the category button that was clicked already changed color?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is not possible because the **Slide** > **Edit master** > **Colors** options include *Link* but don't include *Followed Link*

[image]

Related

- [How to change the default link color in Google Slides?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/112427/88163)